# Refactoring nested For-Loops

Tags: java, for-loop, refactoring, boolean-logic

I was trying to refactor a code snippet I found online for a picture program, and I was just wondering if anyone could help me out. The author of the original code chose to use nested for loops, which I know isn't correct. Any ideas to help me work it out?

```
for (int x = 0; x < this.width(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < this.height(); y++) {
        if (!this.getColor(x, y).equals(typeCastedPicture.getColor(x, y))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I initially just tried using private methods as the solution; however, the problem I'm running into is because it's of type boolean. I'm just not certain how to refactor properly without skewing the semantics. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code works 100% correctly as is; however I'm currently using eclipse and the checkstyle flags any time you code in nested blocks. I just wanted to see if any of you guys could help me figure out how to get the same effect without using nested loops.

Comment: You state: "*The author of the original code chose to use nested for loops, which I know isn't correct.*"  Why? What seems to be wrong with this code?

Comment: looks very correct to me.

Comment: You may have two open brackets on that first loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible but not without making the code stinky. The reason why nested loops are great in your case is that you're iterating over a n*n matrix. It seems like pretty good practice to do in a systematic and direct way.

Anyhow, if you're just interested, consider that we only need to replicate the nested loop behavior in a linear fashion. That is to say we need to unravel the nested loop. Here's an example...

```
for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < this.width();) {
    if (!this.getColor(x, y).equals(typeCastedPicture.getColor(x, y))) {
        return false;
    }
    if ( y == this.height() - 1 ) {
        y = 0;
        x++;
    } else ++y;
}
```

This should give the same results.

This could've been done with a `while` or `do`/`while` loop with enough creativity but that would require even more manual control over the sentinels. The beauty of the nested `for` is it's all handled for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) You were the only person who gave the answer that I was looking for. I just didn't understand how to logically achieve the same effect without using an n*n matrix.

Comment: No problem. Other users may rightfully point out important parts you may be confused on; I just answered the question :) @Ashton.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit of a duplicate answer, but ill try to be a bit more in depth.
Your comment suggest that you wish to refactor something because nested blocks are not best practices. Whilst this is true, its not necessarily a good reason to refactor it.

Refactoring should be done to increase code quality. Now there are lots of opinions of what good quality code is, but for myself readability is a big factor in this. Always favour readability over performance (the reason why nested loops is a bad practice), unless you have a mayor performance issue.

In this case, the code is perfectly readable and very easy to understand, and i dont see this piece of code being your biggest performace issue, so i would suggest leaving it as it is, since all the alternatives will be harder to understand.

(if you would have a lot of operations inside the second loop i would have suggested a:

```
for(...){
   for(...){
     fooBar(x,y);
   }
 }
```

construction to keep it readable)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I understand where you're coming from, and I'll keep it in consideration. I just wanted all the checkstyle errors to go away. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int x = 0, width = this.width(); x < width; x++) {    
    for (int y = 0, height = this.height(); y < height; y++) {
        if (!this.getColor(x, y).equals(
            typeCastedPicture.getColor(x, y))) {
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I just tweaked the code to improve the performance a little!! Other than this, I don't see any issues with the code.

Comment: You're 100% right, the code compiles. I just wanted to refactor the code so that I didn't use any nested blocks. I'm currently using eclipse, and the checkstyle says that nested blocks are not best practices, which is why I was trying to refactor it.